# Copy Current Env Vars into `docker run`'s Scope

Tags: bash, docker, environment-variables

If I'm using a docker container with an entry point set, I can run that container via the following command

```
docker run -it my-container-tag
```

If the program in my container requires an environmental variable, I can pass that var via the -e flag

```
docker run -it -e FOO=bar my-container-tag
```

If I have a program that uses many environment variable, I get an unwieldy mess that becomes hard to type.

```
docker run -it -e FOO=bar -e BAZ=zip -e ZAP=zing -e ETC=omg-stop my-container-tag
```

Is there a way to tell `docker run` to inherit all the env variables currently set in my shell's scope?  If not, are there common practices for working around needing to type in these variables again and again?

Answer (score 1):

You cant inherit the envs, I usually use docker-compose to set my envs when there is too much, or build the container with the environments variables inside it if you dont need to change frequently.